# Ionic Framework for Sound Tracks

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I want to make an iOS app with Ionic framework.

Can I modify sound tracks with Ionic framework such as the pitch and tones?

What's the limit of Ionic framework?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No.   Ionic will assist you *nothing* in this regards.   it's more of a layout framework (style+directives),   it has nothing to do with audio processing..

Take a look at:
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/
https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be more limited by what you can do audio-wise in a webview

see:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/
http://caniuse.com/audio

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.